# Send data changing page Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm

I'm trying to change page and send some data to the new page just create. Basicaly, I have a page where the user could log, I'm gonna save the informations and then I'm going to open a new page by sendind the information to my "profil" page, where the user will have the information about his account. I'm using the MVVM patern, I don't know if it's going to change something but I ad this precision ;).

Edit: The only solution i have found is to pass the string of my object (gladly it is just strings). Because we can pass strings to another page. But I would prefer to give my object directly, or change my architecture if needed. Like don't create a page but replace my Usercontroles by others :(.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**For temp data**:

If it is WP silverlight app, we can directly assign object to public property of destination page in OnNavigateFrom event of source page. For example, we can declare a public property A on Dest page, and implement the following in Source page to pass the user object:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Dest destPage = e.Content as Dest;
        if(destPage != null)
        {
            User a = new User();
            a.UserName = "aa";
            a.ID = 1;
            destPage.A = a;
        }
    }
```

For WP runtime app on WP 8.1, you can directly use Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object) to pass the parameter.

**For persist data**:

I will suggest storing the data to local storage on source page and read it from destination page.

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understandant your code. I never navigate to a new page. The Dest destPage = e.Content as Dest; line is the one I don't understand. You can create a page and then navigate on it ? Because this is where I saw how to navigate on it: [navigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: What you mean by persist data is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070221/how-to-create-a-settings-page-for-windows-8-1-apps) ?

Comment: If you never navigate to a new page, forgot what I mentioned about the navigation. So you need a place to store the object. The place can be a file(you can create one by yourself or using IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings as KiShOrE mentioned) or a local database. IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings can be used for silverlight app for both 8.0 and 8.1. So will suggest you accept KiShOrE's suggestion for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you should use parameters in navigate URI
For example to send name you can use:

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page.xaml?name=UserName", UriKind.Relative));`

and then in OnNavigatedTo() check name parameter:

`string name;
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["keyname"]=yourobject;`
And whenever you want to use this value just unbox this value as below,

```js
if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("keyname"))
{
    var obj=(yourobject)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["keyname"];
}
```